# getting addres of stl vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, casting

I am trying to assign the address of `std::vector<char>` into a `char*` and have some problems.

**code** :

```
void GGG:foo(std::vector<char>& MyVct)  
{  
      char* p = &MyVct[0];   
}
```

But I do not get the address.
How to get the address and cast it into a char* ?

Comment: Do you want the address of the actual `vector` instance, the data inside the vector, or the address of a specific entry in the vector?

Comment: What makes you think you don't get the address? Assuming `MyVct` actually has something in it.

Comment: What do you mean with *I do not get the address*? The standard guarantees this to work unless the vector is empty.

Comment: You need to set the vector's size before executing that code. As long as the vector is empty, `MyVct[0]` is illegal.

Comment: A less hacky way is to use [std::vector::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)... but define "address".

Comment: I want the address of the data in order to modify it

Comment: You don't need to manipulate pointers to modify data inside vector, just access it via vectors interface

Comment: If there is any data to modify, that will get you the address. What makes you think it's not giving you the address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want the address of the element inside the `MyVct` and not the vector itself.
You can use [`vector::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) for this purpose:

```
char* p = MyVct.data();
```

**Edit**: If you want to modify the elements of a vector, you don't have to get its pointer really. You can use the available interfaces provided by [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). For example, instead of doing:

```
char *p = MyVct.data(); // or char *p = &MyVct[0];
*p = 'a';
```

Simply do:

```
MyVct[0] = 'a'; // Use C++ way!
```

Comment: For non-empty vectors this is the same as the asker does already. His question is not clear enough to be answered like this.

Comment: @phresnel, in OP's comment he mentions that he wants the address of data inside vector. Yes, `&MyVct[0]` is correct, but then `MyVct.data()` is more elegant IMO as the reader doesn't have to worry about the operator precedence of `&` and `[]`

Comment: I do not have C++11, any other way ?

Comment: @iammilind: I understand your answer to imply that `MyVct[0]` is wrong, because it stands in contrast to the question.

Comment: @BigLeonardo: Yes. For non-empty vectors, you can use your solution in pre-C++11.

Comment: Of course, while calling `data()` on an empty vector is legal, the resulting pointer isn't good for much.  Specifically, it isn't legal to dereference it.

Comment: @BenVoigt,ofcourse there should be a check for `size()` if there is an uncertainty. Or rather we can use `&MyVct.at(0)`, which will throw an exception in case of out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will indeed get the address of the first element in `MyVct`, assuming there is a first element. In C++11, `std::vector` provides the `data` member function to access the underlying data:

```
char* p = MyVct.data();
```

If you attempt to print this address with `std::cout << p`, you'll find that it gives you some strange output. That's because it expects a `char*` to be a C-style string. If you want to print the address, do:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(p) << std::endl;
```

If, as you say, all you want to do is modify the data in the vector, you only have to do something like this, setting the first element to `'a'`:

```
MyVct[0] = 'a';
```

If instead you want the address of the `vector`, you'll need:

```
std::vector<char>* p = &MyVct;
```

Comment: Is there a nother way without using C++11 ?

Comment: Yes, there is and you did it in your question.